# Subsubsection labels incorrectly starting at 2

Tags: sectioning, renewcommand

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\alph{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\roman{subsection}}

\begin{document}
    
    \section{Question 1}
    \subsection{}
    Subsection 1
    
    \subsection{}
        \subsubsection{}
        Text
    
    
\end{document}
```

For some reason, the first subsubsection starts at 1.b.ii instead of 1.b.i. When I remove the second \renewcommand, it correctly labels it as 1.b.1, but I want roman numerals. How do I fix this?

Comment: you meant `\roman{subsubsection}` not `\roman{subsection}` in the second definition

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ah jeez, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you have `subsection` in there, not `subsubsection`. Try

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\alph{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\roman{subsubsection}}

\begin{document}
    
    \section{Question 1}
    \subsection{}
    Subsection 1
    
    \subsection{}
        \subsubsection{}
        Text
    
    
\end{document}
```

(EDIT: I see @David Carlisle beat me to it and already answered this in a comment.)

Comment: Yes, this was it. Thank you anyways!